# import smtplibで書籍通りにプログラムを書いて実行したが、passかusernameが間違っているといわれる。

Tags: python, smtplib

このようなスクリプトを書きました。
自分のメールアドレスとパスワードを入力しているのにログインできません。
エラー内容は次の通りです。

> SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.0 (#AUTH012) Incorrect username
>   or password.')

エラーをどう解決すればよいか見当もつきません、何か調べたほうが良い事などありますでしょうか？

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header

charset = 'iso-2022-jp'

msg=MIMEText('###', 'plain', charset)
msg['Subject'] = Header('###'.encode(charset), charset)

smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 587)#接続
smtp_obj.ehlo()#問い合わせ
smtp_obj.starttls()#TLSモードに
my =
p =
y =
smtp_obj.login(my, p)#メルアドとpass
smtp_obj.sendmail(my, y, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: [SMTP over SSL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL)を使いましょう。ポートは465。セキュリティを外す[設定](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283538/622121)でもイケると思いますが、今時パスワードを平文で流すのはやめた方がいいです。

Comment: `.com` で合ってます? `.co.jp` では?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。SMTP over SSLというのはちらっと情報を見ました。（暗号化される？）パスワードの話はinput()でやったほうがいいと書籍にも書いてありました。masm様の言う通り.co.jpかもしれませんちょっと試してみます。

Comment: yahooもgoogleもsmtpを利用するには設定が必要な模様です。